# passing list in another list from jquery to controller in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How to send 'things' with list of Bins data to controller method? I am getting all data except Bins Data?  Bins is showing as null with count as 0.

even I tried stringifying both bins and data values but did not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var bins=[{'binName':testbiname,'isSelected':true}]
        var things = [
            { id: 1, color: 'yellow',Bins:bins },
        ];  



    things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/PassThings',
        data: things,
        success: function () {          
            $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    }); 
    });


    public void PassThings(List<Thing> things)
    {
        var t = things;
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    *public list<BinSelecter> Bins{get;set;}*
    }

public class BinSelecter 
{
public string binName {get;set;}
public bool isSelected {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: your javascript Things don't contain any Bins objects

Comment: can you show model of BinSelecter?

Answer (score 0):

let suppose your `BinSelecter` has following properties

```
public class BinSelecter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

so you can add it to your things list like

```
var Binsdata  = [
    { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
    { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
    { id: 3, color: 'red' }
];    

var things = [
    { id: 1, color: 'yellow',Bins:Binsdata },
    { id: 2, color: 'blue',Bins:Binsdata},
    { id: 3, color: 'red',Bins:Binsdata }
];
```